# Ex-Employer holding my salary. How can I take it.?

Tags: salary

I recently resigned from a company and that company is holding my salary telling they can't process it because of Christmas. My then manager was the reason why me and a colleague left the company and he is now refusing to do the clearance putting Christmas staff outage as a reason. I went upto the general manager but no positive result. And also this company is trying to do deductions from my salary. Its already 1 month from my resignation effective date but they asking another month and a half to release the salary. I filed a case in Labour department of sri lanka on this but it seems like it is also going to take time to come to a solution. How can I tackle this problem so the company releases my salary.?

Comment: You have already done all that we could tell you to do by going over your managers head and filing a dispute with the labour department.

Answer (score 3):

> I filed a case in Labour department of sri lanka on this but it seems
>   like it is also going to take time to come to a solution. How can I
>   tackle this problem so the company releases my salary.?

You might try letting the company know that you filed a case with the Labour Department. That might prompt them to start their process. Or not.